# Can GPS Spoofing enhance your privacy or are there other variables to also look at

Tags: privacy, spoofing, gps

With more and more devices and applications pulling meta data like GPS, does GPS spoofing add any value to protecting your privacy or are there other variables that also need to be taken in to account to better keep your location private?

The problem is more and more applications also want or need GPS on to even work properly or even start so simply disabling GPS does not work anymore for some applications.

Comment: they can get an accurate location using "harmless" wifi names, no need for GPS perms.

Comment: If you are that worried, switch to a more secure OS and use fewer apps. Also, on your more secure OS, you will have controls that turn off/on locations services by app. There really aren't that many apps that actually NEED location data.